# How can I run "grub-customizer" on Ubuntu 12:04

Tags: grub2

I need to clear up my start up screen and re-order.  I have down loaded the grub-customizer apt but don't know how to run it. any and all suggestions greatfully received

Answer (score 1):

OK, To install Grub-Customizer, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once installed, search for it in Dash, and then click on the icon, and it will open.  See images below.

[image]
[image]

To run it from terminal type:

```
sudo grub-customizer
```

Comment: Unfortunately once installed, It does not appear within 'Dash' that's my problem. It appears to have downloaded cos I can see reference to it within my home folder - /home/etc/apt .... so how to run it?

Comment: I added the command to start from terminal in my answer.  Give it a try.