# "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu 13.10" in my Grub boot list

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have got "Ubuntu" as well as "Ubuntu 13.10" in the list of boot-able partitions when Grub appears. How can I fix this? This is what my grub looks like:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Ubuntu 13.10
- Advanced options for Ubuntu 13.10
- Windows 7 (loader)

How can I get rid of the duplicate Ubuntu entries in the Grub boot list?

EDIT: `sudo update-grub2` didn't work, but it does show this:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found Ubuntu 13.10 (13.10) on /dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Linux2
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/mapper/isw_dcgidgaidc_Win7p1
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo update-grub2` should be enough to fix the duplicate entries.

Comment: Nope I still have "Ubuntu" and "Ubuntu 13.10" in the list

Comment: You can use grub-customizer to check the scripts & find out if these are indeed duplicate entries, and then delete them manually if necessary: http://askubuntu.com/questions/295666/how-can-i-run-grub-customizer-on-ubuntu-1204

Comment: Could you give me some advice what I need to do within grub-customizer? Have never used it before

Comment: For example if I right-click the "Ubuntu" and "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and clicked "delete" would that work?

Comment: You can start from here: https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1355

Comment: To be honest they arent clear enough exactly what I need to do- I dont want to get this wrong. Looks like the duplicate Ubuntu entry relates to vmlinuz

Comment: Relates to vmlinuz? Meaning old kernel headers? These entries would probably look different if it was the case. Anyway, you don't really "delete" entries with grub2, you rather disable them. But if you want to know where these entries are coming from, you can look at the scripts, for which you can use grub-customizer as well.